# Creating a more advanced scheduler

Tags: c++, scheduler

So i am going to be upgrading some scheduler code and it is currently very dumb. I would love to upgrade the code to be similar to Outlook's every Monday at 5 etc. or every third Thursday of the month.

Current schedule system can not specify a day of the week only a period like (daily, weekly, monthly, annually) and can not specify time, or a specific day, like weekly is only on Friday. and the daily is only at 7 am. (so weekly would be Friday at 7 am)

Are there any resources that I can look up to understand how this would work?
 My Google searches so far have turned up nothing useful, due to using the word outlook.

Comment: Actually i found this :) The Zeller Congruence will help me a lot http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Boost.Date_Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/date_time.html) should give you the date manipulation functions you need.  Should be easier to use their (debugged) code rather than trying to reinvent it.